# What causes this 'index not found' error in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an app that seems to run fine, but my logs get a few lines like this each day...

```
ERROR - 2015-07-30 12:19:07 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined index: HTTP_HOST /application/config/database.php 67
ERROR - 2015-07-30 12:19:07 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined index: HTTP_HOST /application/config/database.php 68
ERROR - 2015-07-30 12:19:07 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined index: HTTP_HOST /application/config/database.php 69
ERROR - 2015-07-30 12:19:07 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined index: HTTP_HOST /application/controllers/Inc.php 15
```

As I said, the app seems to be running properly but I depend on using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] to ensure proper execution. Is this a known issue with CodeIgniter 3? Especially the database config. I use different databases depending on which instance I am on.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` you can try using `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`
The problem is that your server is not sending HTTP_HOST into $_SERVER global variable. This is case many times which varies from server to server